# Overwrote 60MB of mounted filesystem from other filesystem with dd

Tags: linux, dd, restore

I had mounted ext4 filesystem (/dev/sdg1) and accidentally did `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdg` and `CTRL-C` after 1 second, so only 60 MB data has been transferred.
`/dev/sda1` has ext3 root filesystem.
What I have now:

1. Restored partition on `sdg` (as it was rewrited from `sda`)
2. All superblocks on `sdg1` are from `sda1`

Any ideas to restore data?

Answer (score 2):

In general this can be very hard. You can try with tools like:

[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), [ForeMost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/)

but you must be sure you have enough disk space (other than sdg1) where to store restored file.

The most clear way to do is to recreate filesystem on sdg1 and restore from backup (if you have)

Answer (score 2):

To restore the data from a situation like this you will almost certainly need to dig out your backups. Unfortunately.